# Components e Services

Tags: angular, lógica

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e me deparei com o seguinte problema:

estou trabalhando com uma api que gerencia um website e tenho alguns endpoints como: **banners**, **depoimentos**, **usuario**, **imagens** etc, a maioria dos endpoints possui alguma relação com *imagens*, então resolvi criar um endpoint **imagens** para centralizar os uploads, todas as imagens são enviadas para este endpoint **imagens** onde é feita as validações necessárias.

quando vou realizar algum cadastro que precise de imagens, eu primeiro faço o cadastro da imagem no endpoint **imagens** que me retorna um array com os ids dos registro do banco de dados onde eu guardo os diretorios, o site é em angular, criei um componente `fileinput` para receber as imagens, esse componente possui um `serviceA` que conecta com a api no endpoit imagens, minha duvida cai aqui: apos ser feita o envio da imagem para o servidor e me devolvido os ids; quem tem acesso é o `serviceA` do `fileinput`, porem eu completo o cadastro com o `componentB` que usa o `serviceB` como eu posso fazer para trazer o retorno do `serviceA` para dentro do `serviceB`?

Comment: @Injectable... 
Injeta o serviceA no serviceB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode injetar um serviço dentro de outro.

No seu serviço A crie um methodo que retorna o que deseja:

```
@Injectable()
export class valores {
 checValues(){
    return this.values;}}
```

Esse methodo será injetado no serviço B da seguinte forma:

```
constructor(
    private valueService: valores) { }
```

E para chamar o methodo:

```
this.valueService.checkValues();
```

Caso tenha dúvidas, veja o vídeo abaixo:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMhCDO75Aus&list=PLGxZ4Rq3BOBoSRcKWEdQACbUCNWLczg2G&index=43